# Add to map inside of parse dialect

Tags: rebol, rebol3, red

I want to create a `map` where a hash is associated to a url in order to check if some url is or is not in the `map`.
If it's not yet in the `map`, add it (and the url) to it.

```
parseContainer: func [cstr [string!]] [
    parse cstr [
        thru "<a href=" to {"}
        thru "http://" copy quarto_url to {"}
        (
            quarto_hash: checksum/method to-binary quarto_url 'md5
            old: find words-of checksums 'quarto_hash
            if not old [append checksums [quarto_hash quarto_url ]]
        )
    ]
]
```

But the words `quarto_hash` and `quarto_url` are not converted to their values.
This is maybe not the simplest approach for the problem, so I'll wait for your input.
One other question: is `map` able to address insertion and search of elements quickly for thousands of elements, or is there any other more appropriate type?

FYI, I'm using `Rebol3`, but included the `Red` tag as well because I'll also be using `Red` in a short future.
What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce the words **quarto_hash** and **quarto_url**

```
if not old [append checksums reduce [quarto_hash quarto_url ]]
```

There is also no need to extract the words of the map, you should be faster with a select direct on the map

I would use

```
if not select checksums quarto_hash [
    append checksums reduce [quarto_hash quarto_url ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do one of the following:

```
if not old [repend checksums [quarto_hash quarto_url]]
```

or

```
if not old [append checksums reduce [quarto_hash quarto_url]]
```

You will now find that `quarto_hash` and `quarto_url` are evaluated before adding into the `checksums` (hash)map.

With regards to `map` insertion/searching you will find examples below easier/faster:

```
>> checksums: map []
== make map! [
]

>> quarto-url: "www.draegtun.com"
== "www.draegtun.com"

>> quarto-hash: checksum/method to-binary quarto-url 'md5
== #{D9F71DD455C3E84E7C5C8F2C23FDF174}

>> checksums/:quarto-hash
== none

>> ;;  returns NONE if key not present in map

>> checksums/:quarto-hash: quarto-url    
== "www.draegtun.com"

>> checksums
== make map! [
    #{D9F71DD455C3E84E7C5C8F2C23FDF174} "www.draegtun.com"
]
```

Comment: Interesting syntax of `checksums/:quarto-hash: quarto-url` but doesn't work in my 3.0.0.4.40 Rebol 3 interpreter.

Comment: Hi @Luis,  The above examples use the [path!](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/path.html) syntax and this usage was designed specifically for Rebol 3 (they were entered verbatim into Rebol console here and copy/pasted into answer).  What errors did you get?

Comment: Sorry, tried again in a new console and it worked :-)  Thank you very much for your explanation!